Problema en backend NodeJS
Estoy teniendo dificultades con mi proyecto en el backend. Actualmente estoy trabajando en una aplicación que gestiona la subida de imágenes y genera una URL correspondiente para cada una de ellas.
En el frontend, al hacer la solicitud a /upload en el backend, estoy obteniendo un error 500, que indica un problema interno del servidor.
POST https://api-image-upload-app.vercel.app/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
Adjunto el código del backend para que puedan ayudarme a identificar y solucionar el problema. Agradezco cualquier orientación que puedan brindarme.
BACKEND
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Configurar Multer para gestionar la subida de archivos
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Rutas de la API
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).send('No se ha seleccionado ningún archivo');
    }

    res.send(`Archivo guardado: ${req.file.filename}`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

// Arrancar la API
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API de subida de imágenes en http://localhost:${port}`);
});

FRONTEND
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

function App() {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    const onSubmit = async (files) => {
        if (files.length === 0) {
            return setMessage('No se ha seleccionado ningún archivo');
        }

        const file = files[0]; // Acceder al primer archivo seleccionado

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('image', file);

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('https://api-image-upload-app.vercel.app/upload', data, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
            });
            setImage(file);
            setMessage(`Archivo guardado: ${response.data}`);
        } catch (error) {
            setMessage('Ocurrió un error al guardar el archivo');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto', width: '500px' }}>
            <h1>Subir Imágenes</h1>
            <Dropzone onDrop={onSubmit}>
                {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                    <div {...getRootProps()} style={{ border: '2px dashed #ccc', padding: '10px' }}>
                        <input {...getInputProps()} />
                        <p>Arrastra y suelta una imagen aquí o haz clic para seleccionar archivo</p>
                    </div>
                )}
            </Dropzone>
            <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;


Esta pregunta ya tiene dos votos positivos y no has proporcionado retroalimentación en relación a la respuesta proporcionada abajo.

Amigo ya vi cual es el fallo! creo que el problema es el deployment en vercel. Al subir el backend express a vercel, este funciona como una function serverless que no permite escribir archivos directamente sobre ella, revisa los logs de tu servidor en vercel y veras el error


Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

Parece una respuesta válida pero complementa esta respuesta con el código que propones en la otra respuesta abajo e indica cual fue el cambio que hiciste en node para que funcionara correctamente. Luego elimina la respuesta de abajo o seguirás recibiendo votos negativos por parte de la comunidad.

const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;
const uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')
// Configuración de Multer para almacenar los archivos en disco
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, uploadDir);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });


//middleware para hacer publica la carpeta uploads
app.use('/uploads', express.static(uploadDir));

// Ruta para subir un archivo
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.send('Archivo subido correctamente');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor escuchando en http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});


Amigo prueba con esto y te debe funcionar, saludos!

tambien verifica que exista la carpeta uploads antes de intentar guardar en ella las imagenes.

Amigo ya vi cual es el fallo! creo que el problema es el deployment en vercel. Al subir el backend express a vercel, este funciona como una function serverless que no permite escribir archivos directamente sobre ella, revisa los logs de tu servidor en vercel y veras el error

Hola Ioannis, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, te comento que las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja validad, por otro lado, dar más de una respuesta tampoco ayuda, para evitar que tu respuesta sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos, te sugiero que la edites y expliques suscintamente de que forma soluciona el problema plantaeado.

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
